# how to convert a non linear feature into a linear feature?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, regression-coefficients

For logistic regression to work well we need to convert a non linear feature to a linear feature. how should one determine whether a feature is linear or not? How should one convert a non-linear feature to a linear feature?

Comment: You can convert a non-linear feature to a linear feature in some cases by suitable data transformation. This answer is as general as your question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a non-linear feature?  Of what is it a non-linear function?  Do you mean that the *relationship* between a feature and some other variable is non-linear?

Answer (score 1):

Use a Taylor series to approximate your non linear variable.  Very general answer.

Comment: (+1) For the question "How to convert a non linear feature into a linear feature?", the judges would have also accepted the answers "Locally." or "Linearize." However points will not be subtracted for the excessive length of this answer. </sarcasm>

Comment: We thank the judges' generosity </~sarcasm>

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If your feature is non-linear, meaning it involves non-linear operations on the inputs, a linear version of it will lose information about the true relation between the input dimensions. However, if you're willing to lose this information(which might have a huge effect on your accuracy),you can use linear regression and take the most probable hyperplane.